# Error when i send HTML mail template on Django

Tags: python, html, django, email, django-templates

I am trying to send email using a template HTML on Django, but i having a problem with encode error

My code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context


d = Context({'nome' : 'Gerento'})
htmly = get_template('teste_template.html')
html_content = htmly.render(d)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('dhfusafi', 'teste', 'no-reply@teste.com', ['guilherme@teste.com'])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'html/text')
msg.send()
```

When i run it, i get it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "teste.py", line 12, in <module>
    msg.send()
  File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 107, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 121, in _send
    message = email_message.message()
  File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 256, in message
    msg = self._create_message(msg)
  File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 444, in _create_message
    return self._create_attachments(self._create_alternatives(msg))
  File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 454, in _create_alternatives
    msg.attach(self._create_mime_attachment(*alternative))
  File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/martizi-api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 387, in _create_mime_attachment
    Encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 45, in encode_base64
    encdata = _bencode(orig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 32, in _bencode
    value = base64.encodestring(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 315, in encodestring
    pieces.append(binascii.b2a_base64(chunk))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I did a simple test: i change my template html with a lot style to a simple html, just a test and it worked! So, i believe this problem is with my template. 
A block piece of my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <!-- NAME: 1 COLUMN -->
        <!--[if gte mso 15]>
        <xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        p{
            margin:10px 0;
            padding:0;
        }
        table{
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
            display:block;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        img,a img{
            border:0;
            height:auto;
            outline:none;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            width:100%;
        }
        #outlook a{
            padding:0;
        }
        img{
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }
        table{
            mso-table-lspace:0pt;
            mso-table-rspace:0pt;
        }
        .ReadMsgBody{
            width:100%;
        }
        .ExternalClass{
            width:100%;
        }
        p,a,li,td,blockquote{
            mso-line-height-rule:exactly;
        }
        a[href^=tel],a[href^=sms]{
            color:inherit;
            cursor:default;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

Anyone have any idea what i do?

*Sorry for my terrible English :(

tks )

Comment: Try encoding the rendered template ast utf-8: `html_content = htmly.render(d).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Thanks! 
Apparently the code it worked, encode error not appear anymore, but the mail is not coming to my mail box. Any idea?

Thank you! @Alasdair

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell why your mail is being delivered, and it sounds like a separate problem. It depends on your email settings and provider. Make sure that your email provider allows you to send email as the address you are using (`no-reply@teste.com`).

Comment: Thanks, @Alasdair
I discovery why the email not coming to my mail box, because my email provider. I direct to another address, gmail address, but i received only text
`msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('dhfusafi', 'teste', 'no-reply@teste.com', ['guilherme@teste.com']) `

subject dhfusafi and body of email 'teste'
The template html is not coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the rendered template as utf-8 before attaching it to the email.

```
html_content = htmly.render(d).encode('utf-8')
```

If you don't encode it, Django will try to encode it as ascii, giving you the error.

Comment: thanks!

This lib EmailMultiAlternatives doesnt work.

I try this:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

subject = 'Eu sou HTML'
to = ['teste@gmail.com']
from_email = 'no-reply@teste.com'

ctx = {'nome' : 'Gerento'}
message = get_template('confirma_cadastro.html').render(Context(ctx))
msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=to, from_email=from_email)
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()`